# Continuity of normalized displacement vector for a smooth closed curve

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I am currently working on chapter 3.12 of "Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems" by Lawrence Perko. I am stuck on the continuity of the function $g$ in Theorem 3. My work (up to the prove of continuity based on Perko with slightly different notation) so far:

Suppose that $f\in C^1(E)$ where $E$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and that $E$ contains a cycle $\Gamma$ of the system $\dot{x}=f(x) \quad(1)$.

At any point $x\in\Gamma$, define the unit vector $u(x)=f(x)/|f(x)|$. We can assume that $\Gamma$ lies in the first quadrant and is tangent to the $x$-axis in some point $(x_0,0),x_0>0$ (otherwise translate and rotate the axis). Let $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ be the solution of $(1)$ through the point $(x_0,0)$ at time $t=0$. We can assume that $\Gamma$ is positively oriented and that the period of $\Gamma$ is equal to $1$, so
\begin{align*}\Gamma=\{\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))\in\mathbb{R}^2~|~0\leq t\leq 1\}.\end{align*}

Let $T=\{(s,t)\in\mathbb{R}^2~|~0\leq s\leq t\leq 1\}$, then for $(s,t)\in T$ we define the vector field $g$ by
\begin{align*}&g(s,s)=u(\gamma(s)), & 0\leq s\leq 1 \\ &g(0,1)=-u(\gamma(0)), & \\ &g(s,t)=\frac{\gamma(t)-\gamma(s)}{|\gamma(t)-\gamma(s)|}, & 0\leq s < t \leq 1\end{align*}

Now Perko states, that $g$ is continuous on $T$ and $g\neq 0$ for on $T$.

It is clear that $g$ is continuous on $\tilde{T}:=T\setminus\{(s,t)\in T~|~s=t \vee (s,t)=(0,1)\}$. Let $(s_n,t_n)\rightarrow (s,s),0\leq s\leq 1$. One can show that
\begin{align*}g(s_n,t_n)=\frac{\gamma(t_n)-\gamma(s_n)}{|\gamma(t_n)-\gamma(s_n)|}=\frac{\frac{\gamma(t_n)-\gamma(s_n)}{t_n-s_n}}{\frac{|\gamma(t_n)-\gamma(s_n)|}{t_n-s_n}}\stackrel{s_n<t_n}{=}\frac{\frac{\gamma(t_n)-\gamma(s_n)}{t_n-s_n}}{\left|\frac{\gamma(t_n)-\gamma(s_n)}{t_n-s_n}\right|}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\rightarrow} \frac{\dot{\gamma(s)}}{|\dot{\gamma(s)}|}\stackrel{\dot{\gamma}=f(\gamma)}{=}u(\gamma(s)).\end{align*}
I now have problems to prove the continuity of $g$ in $(0,1)$. I have uploaded a pdf with [figures](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhj7edhdfaywux7/figures%20g%28s%2Ct%29.pdf?dl=0) of the problem (is it possible to attach it directly to this post?), just by "looking" one would say that $g(s,t)\rightarrow -u(\gamma(0))$ as $(s,t)\rightarrow (0,1)$, but I don't find a way to really prove it. Any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to avoid complications at endpoints is to not have endpoints. The function $\gamma$ is continuously differentiable and $1$-periodic on all of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\tilde t = t-1$. As $t\to 1$, 
$$\frac{\gamma(t)-\gamma(s)}{|\gamma(t)-\gamma(s)|} = 
\frac{\gamma(\tilde t)-\gamma(s)}{|\gamma(\tilde t)-\gamma(s)|} \to -\gamma'(0)$$
because both $\tilde t$ and $s$ converge to $0$ in such a way that $\tilde t<s$.

The details are exactly as in your computation, except for the reversed inequality between $s_n$ and $t_n$.

Comment: This looks great, thank you! Reading it, it seems so obvious...