# Definition of "vector fields never have opposite direction"

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, definition, vector-fields

Good day!

As in [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1323537/continuity-of-a-function-in-one-point) I am referring to the book "Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems" by Lawrence Perko, chapter 3.12. I have a question regarding Lemma 2:

> Lemma 2. If $v$ and $w$ are two continuous vector fields defined on a Jordan Curve $C$ which never have opposite directions or are zero on $C$, then $I_v(C)=I_w(C)$.

What is the definition of "never having opposite directions" for the vector fields $v,w\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ (or $v,w\in C^1(E)$ where $E$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$). I couldn't find a definition in Perko's book for this.

Comment: I found this definition which might serve: https://books.google.com/books?id=-nX1CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=vector+field+never+having+opposite+directions&source=bl&ots=W42rIyNfs1&sig=Biv0BnLcsI4eGS_sP0JQWpOptcs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAmoVChMIyfusz7uMxgIVUzGMCh3KlgBv#v=onepage&q=vector%20field%20never%20having%20opposite%20directions&f=false. According to that it means $v/||v||+w/||w||$ never vanishes on $C$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll check it out and see if it fits!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KittyL is right: not having opposite direction means $v/\|v\| \ne  - w/\|w\|$.

It's worth noting that both conditions (nonvanishing and not pointing in opposite directions) can be combined into one: 
$$
t v + (1-t) w \ne 0 \quad \text{ for } t\in [0,1]
$$
The latter, not coincidentally, is exactly what you need to argue $I_v=I_w$ by means of straight-line homotopy.

Comment: Thank you! With this definition I've worked my way through the proof of this lemma and it went quite smoothly. :)